# how to configure drools without eclipse or any other IDE

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine

I am getting example like how to install drools plugins in eclipse or other IDE. But how can I configure drools without using any IDE like eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a Maven Project (using your favorite IDE or the comand-line)
2. Add Drools Compiler depedency and some logging compatible library to your pom.xml (main Maven project file):

   ```
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
           <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
           <version>6.3.0.Final</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
           <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
           <version>1.1.5</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ```
3. Create the src/main/resources/META-INF/kmodule.xml file with the contents:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule" />
   ```
4. Create your DRL file like src/main/resources/myrules.drl

   ```
   rule "hello"
       when
           $name : String()
       then
           System.out.println("Hello "+$name);      
   end
   ```
5. Create your KieService based code:

   ```
   import org.kie.api.KieServices;
   import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
   import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;

   public class Main {

       public static void main(String[] args) {

           KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
           KieContainer kcontainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();                
           KieSession ksession = kcontainer.newKieSession();

           String name="Xeetu";      
           ksession.insert(name);

           ksession.fireAllRules();                
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: your answer, combined with @laune worked for me. Just that I noticed it works fine also without the logging dependency. Plus I added the following 2 dependencies for Drools: `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
            <version>7.44.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>` and `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.44.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>`

Answer (score 1):

You can compile DRL and other Drools formats for rule authoring using the Drools API, and you can use a compiled KieBase for creating a session where you execute the rules. Below is one example, but you'll have to adapt it for various reasons.

```
KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieFileSystem kfs = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( "simple/simple.drl" );
kfs.write( "src/main/resources/simple.drl",
           kieServices.getResources().newInputStreamResource( fis ) );
KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder( kfs ).buildAll();
Results results = kieBuilder.getResults();
if( results.hasMessages( Message.Level.ERROR ) ){
     System.out.println( results.getMessages() );
     throw new IllegalStateException( "### errors ###" );
}
KieContainer kieContainer =
    kieServices.newKieContainer( kieServices.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId() );
KieBase kieBase = kieContainer.getKieBase();
kieSession = kieBase.newKieSession();
// ... insert facts ...
kieSession.fireAllRules();
```

Additional calls may be necessary for configuring the KieBase and/or KieSession. See the API and Drools documentation for numerous details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply